# How can I randomize my mac address using bash functions?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm following this tutorial here:

http://osxdaily.com/2008/01/17/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-in-mac-os-x/

and they have some good ideas, but I imagined somebody has already written this into a function or 2?

Do you have to power cycle your wireless adapter to do this?

Comment: The article you link to gives all the commands to both generate and set mac addresses. What have you tried so far? How does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to come up with your own randomization scheme to add to their snippets.

An you will need to combine them intelligently as such:

```
mac_create(){
    echo -n 00-00-00 
    dd bs=1 count=3 if=/dev/random 2>/dev/null | hexdump -v -e '/1 "-%02X"'
}
mac_randomize(){
    sudo ifconfig en0 down
    local mac=$(mac_create)
    sudo ifconfig en0 ether $mac
    sudo ifconfig en0 up
    echo $mac
}
```

This power down your adapter, change the mac, and power it back up.  You need to power up and power down so that the WAP ( white anglo saxon protestants ) knows where you are.